# Как на CSS сделать неполный background?

Tags: html, css

Растягивать на всю ширину, 300px это ширина где будет контент.

Белый цвет хотелось бы его сделать прозрачным (transparent), если нельзя то просто белым.

```css
.container {
  background: #00A3E8;
}
.section {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете ограничить отображение потомка через присваивание родительскому `div` свойств `position:relative; overflow:hidden;` или же воспользоваться заданием  [background-size:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) Не очень понятно чего именно вы хотите достич, но это может вам помочь.